# Привязка Command к нажатию ПКМ

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Когда я записываю следующее:

то при нажатии на кнопку левой кнопкой мыши сработает команда Activate.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатии ПКМ на эту кнопку срабатывала другая команда, допустим onRightClickActivate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте сборку System.Windows.Interactivity и объявите пространство имен:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

После этого на нужное событие мы можем привязать команду следующим образом:

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethingCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877807/6641468)

Comment: Имя "Interaction" не существует в пространстве имен "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity".

Comment: @Draktharon, Саму сборку добавили?

Comment: нет, в этом и была проблема и она решена,спасибо

Comment: @Draktharon, Пожалуйста. Рад, что помог!